# How to add files to IPFS programmatically in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ipfs

I am trying to add files to **IPFS** in **ASP.NET MVC**. I'm using **net-ipfs-api (an IPFS http client library)**. When i try to add a png image file, i get a hash, and with that hash, I am able to browse png image locally on IPFS on address **127.0.0.1:8080/ipfs/QmUJ7seBx3jZrJVRIOg3QWc5SesNdW8wSaNPkbR3OW5DG2**

But the problem is I can't browse file through IPFS gateway  on address **https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmUJ7seBx3jZrJVRIOg3QWc5SesNdW8wSaNPkbR3OW5DG2**

- I have installed IPFS Correctly
- I have daemon up and running
- I have ports open 8080, 4001, 5001
- Gateway is set to 0.0.0.0 (to accept incoming request from any ip address)

Please have a look at below code. what i am missing?

**c# code:**

```
//getting file from user.
var myfile =  HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["getFile"];
var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/uploadedFiles/" + myfile.FileName);


using (var ipfs = new IpfsClient())
 {
   await ipfs.Swarm.Peers();
 IpfsStream inputStream = new IpfsStream(filePath, File.OpenRead(filePath));
 MerkleNode node = await ipfs.Add(inputStream);
 Stream outputStream = await ipfs.Cat(node.Hash.ToString());
}
```

**Ipfs configuration file:**
set to 0.0.0.0 to get request from any ip address

```
"Gateway": "/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/8080",
```

Comment: When this happened to me, it turned out my port/router/gateway configuration still wasn't working even though I'd made changes to allow it to connect.Try to VPN out and check from an external host?

Comment: thanks @DietrichAyala I enabled port forwarding through router's configuration and it worked.

Comment: Yay, glad to hear you fixed it @Mazdaq!